# Generating float based on int

Tags: objective-c, ios8, floating-point, int

I'm making a cricket game so if you have a little idea about cricket you'll easily understand this problem.
I'm stuck at a logic which I cannot figure out. It is regarding total numbers of overs. (1 over means player will throw 6 balls, same 2 overs means 12 balls and so on).
I've been able to get if over is `1` balls left are `6`. And to show how many overs are done I have to show it in a form:
 `0.4`<-(4th ball of 1st over) or 
`1.3`<-(3rd Ball of 2nd over)
similarly when the number reaches `0.6` it will be equal to `1`

So I've the information in `int` and want to display it as `float`. Any logical advice of how can I achieve this.

Comment: Better use `double` than `float`. It seems `float` is coming from old ages when RAM was too small.

Comment: @samgak The correct answer has been given by samgak below, but `float` is enough to represent up to 500000 overs and the number of balls left in each. I don't know anything about cricket but I think this is likely to be enough for most cricket events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use floats at all, because you could get floating point errors. For storing a discrete quantity, use an int. Store the total number of balls as an int and when you want to display it, divide by 6 to get overs and take modulo 6 to get remainder (which ball of the over it is). Add 1 if you want to number your balls within the over starting from 1 instead of 0.

```
int balls = 62; // example value
printf("%d.%d", balls / 6, (balls % 6) + 1);
```

Should output 10.3 (third ball of 11th over)

When balls is zero it is the first ball of the first over (0.1).

If you insist on having a float, you can convert like this:

```
float overs = (float)(balls / 6) + ((float)((balls % 6) + 1) * 0.1f);
```